# How to see from definition that each Borel set can be written as countable union or intersection of open and closed sets?

Tags: real-analysis

This is of course true intuitively because Borel set is generated by collection of open set. But in definition, the Borel sets are intersection of all sigma algebras that contain all open sets. How to see that this definition implies that there is no Borel set such that it cannot be written as a countable combination of open and closed sets.

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "can be written as countable union or intersection of open and closed sets" ?

Comment: @user120527 Every Borel set can be written as $S :=\Lambda_k E_k$ where $E_i$ is either open or closed and $\Lambda$ denotes set union or intersection. That is Borel set can be constructed with open and closed sets via countably union and intersection operation.

Comment: I believe that's false, and that's the reason of this nonconstructive definition of the Borel sigma-algebra, because sets of this kind are not stable under countable unions/intersections, and there is no easy way to fix this.

Comment: @user120527 Can you give a counter example? This is kinda a big deal because I always thought "generating" means you can actually express those that are generated as the generators.

Comment: I don't have example, but perhaps the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1610287/530843 will be useful

Comment: "True intuitively" or not, it's false. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773593/can-we-obtain-the-borel-sigma-algebra-on-01-as-a-limit-of-finite-algebra/2773625#2773625https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773593/can-we-obtain-the-borel-sigma-algebra-on-01-as-a-limit-of-finite-algebra/2773625#2773625 for the real story.